# Magento is randomly resetting product inventory to 0

Tags: inventory

We have a client who has mentioned that inventory on certain items is randomly and magically getting reset to 0, even though it might have had an inventory level of 20 the day before. No, they're not getting 20 orders in one day to set the inventory to 0.

Has anyone experienced similar behavior before? What areas of the code should we look at that might cause such an issue? They only have stamps.com using the API, no other external apps are connecting to the site (aside from CC and shipping APIs).

Comment: Has there been any orders at all for those products that have had their inventory reset to 0?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I'm getting the same problem. I can can set the stock quantity ok but as soon as I view the product page it gets set back to 0 and "out of stock".

Comment: Hi , Did you find an answer for this as well ? I am having the same issue now , we had recently downgraded from Magento Enterprise to  Community 1.9.x

Comment: I did not ever find out what was causing this. I no longer work on the project anymore and it was migrated off of Magento. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: we are having the same issue. We have meticulously gone through logs and calls being made to our third party inventory system. Every time it correctly updates the product to the quantity available. Give it an hour or two and it "re-sets" it to zero. Then we run the sync again and it updates to the correct stock Quantity. Has anyone found an answer for this please? We are on Magento 1.9.3.2 and the items are NOT being sold. Thanx

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145568)

Answer (score 3):

No, I never heard of such things, but I think, debugging might be quite easy: Write an observer, if the inventory is set to 0 log a the whole request, stacktrace, etc.

Comment: Good advice, wish I would have seen this 3 years ago :D